# Earth from Java. It's possible?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I would to know if is posssible create a APP in Java for web without to need to install the plugin. For example I to use Google Earth Libraries for Java and show the Google Earth in a web page without the user to need install the plugin. It's possible? If yes, What I need to do?

I am questioning, because the plugin have a lot of BUGs. For example Suddenly the plugin stopped work in my Mac's Chrome. I am with this problem about 5 months.

Thanks

Comment: You'd solve a problem and create another: most users don't have Java installed in their machines.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right. I was thinking in a applets Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It is not possible. You must use the Javascript API. There was an COM API but now is obsolete (http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/sunset-for-google-earth-com-api.html).
I'm using Google Earth API with Chrome in Mac and yes it has some bugs, but I think it's usable.